# Error OData Source SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, odata, sql-server-2016

I'm using SQL Server 2016 with SharePoint 2013. I'm trying to access to SharePoint List.
I use the OData Source in my Package. The connection works succefully and I can preview (with the Preview button) data from the list.

But, when I try to execute it got an error :

> Error: La connexion « Connexion » est introuvable. Vérifiez que le gestionnaire de connexions renferme une connexion de ce nom.

In English  :

> The connection "connexion" is not found. Check if the connections managers has a connection with this name.

I have no connection named "connexion" in my package.

Do you have any ideas on this error please ?

Comment: Check the `Event Handler`, there might exist task(s), or you could view the package in codes by right clicking the package in the solution viewer - View Code, try to search the connection keyword

Comment: I've checked the code there is no connection named "connexion"  In the code there is just the connection with OData Source <connections>
                <connection
                  refId="Package\Tâche de flux de données\ODataSource.Connections[Connection]"
                  connectionManagerID="{A6F82D06-59FE-4389-BFB9-BF9F958B8017}:external"
                  connectionManagerRefId="Project.ConnectionManagers[OData Source Connection]"
                  description="Connection to OData Service"
                  name="Connection" />
              </connections>

Comment: Could you please check if there is a connection manager for logging.  Go to SSIS > Logging in the menu

Comment: No connection manager in Logging

Comment: i have the same probleme is there any solution yet please ?